# mysql-server installation stops

Tags: 16.04, server, software-installation, ssh, mysql

I recently just got an unmanaged VPS running Ubuntu 16.04 from OVH and am trying to install MySQL on it.
I first run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then once I have all the update packages, I run:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Now when I do that, it starts running, asks if I want to continue, I say yes, then asks to create a password for the root user which I do.
Once I do that it continues the installation until it gets to

```
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
```

Then it just freezes and stops. I let it run for an hour yesterday and still nothing happened. So I just closed the SSH session and logged back in hoping it would work, but when I try to login to MySQL, it just says:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I checked the files through SFTP and that file doesn't even exist!

I had nothing on my VPS so I just reset it because I was too lazy to find a solution to purge MySQL since it too was giving me an error message, but that's not the problem.

So now I have a clear VPS with nothing on it except the default Ubuntu folders and files, it would be nice if anyone had an idea on what to do to successfully install mysql-server.

Thanks! :)